# Rate my app functionality - getting correct store for user's apple id

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I know to open the app store to rate its just a matter of setting the NSURL to the address of the app in iTunes. But what if you want the user to rate the app from the App Store they got it from i.e. if they are in Spain but have a US account, i want them to rate it in the US store.

Using from NSLocaleCountryCode may take them to the wrong App Store. Is there a way to determine which country App Store they downloaded the app from or which app store they are signed in with on their device?